# How do you use delete, update, insert in joomla mvc from the file you create

Tags: database, model-view-controller, joomla, delete-row

I have been able to create simple MVC app to display the form and use information from the database. [ so sql I use SELECT ].

However, when I use 'update' or 'delete' the data in the database stay the same. I don't understand!?!

[ I use controller.php call model and pass id to match with the row in the table]

1. I check data that pass in there, and it did echo the value of id.
2. The page I load from the controller that call method in model has complete without the error (it could be that the syntax is right, but logic is wrong).
3. so i start to change sql statement to SELECT and it gives me the value that match with $id param'

I don't understand? any clue?

```
 $query = JFactory::getDbo()->getQuery(true);

 $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
 $query = "DELETE FROM `menutables`  WHERE `id2` = $id ";


$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query(); // this line I also take it out to test, it is fine but no data change either
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you try to modify a Joomla database or a personal one?

Look at this pages :
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_connect_to_an_external_database
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script#Tips.2C_Tricks_.26_FAQ

Answer (score 0):

try to use either

$query = "DELETE FROM #__menutables  WHERE `id2` = '$id' ";

or

$query = "DELETE FROM #__menutables  WHERE `id2` = '".$id."' ";

it'll work fine then.

Comment: Would you please reformat your code properly? Indent your code with 4 spaces, and make sure the code is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Deleting a Record**

delete query in Joomla 2.5.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// delete all custom keys for user 1001.
$conditions = array(
    $db->quoteName('user_id') . '=1001', 
    $db->quoteName('profile_key') . '=\'custom.%\''
);

$query->delete($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'));
$query->where($conditions);

$db->setQuery($query);
```